# Smoothness of data generated by C++

Tags: c++, matlab

I am trying to plot a function (gaussian function) with C++. The problem is that the outputs are not smooth and plot looks jagged. Below I attach the output of the same function one made with MATLAB and the other with C++ (Note: Plot is zoomed in so just the peak of function is visible to clarify the difference). And here is the C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){        
    int matrix = 100000;
    long double y[matrix], x=0.0, step=0.1;
    double FWHM = 1000, alpha;
    alpha = FWHM/(2*log(2));
    for (int i=0; i<matrix; i++) {
        x = x + step;
        y[i] = exp(-pow((x-3000.0),2.0)/pow(alpha,2.0));
        }
}
```

and this is MATLAB code:

```
matrix = 100000;
x=0.0; step=0.1;
FWHM = 1000; 
    alpha = FWHM/(2*log(2));

    for i=1:matrix
        x = x + step;
        y(i) = exp(-((x-3000.0).^2.0)/alpha.^2.0);
    end
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you store data and plot that? Based on the graph shape, I think you dump y[i] in a text file, read from matlab, and plot them. Also I suspect you didn't set the precision while printing. If you don't set the precision, the default is 6, thus the output will be jagged as you mentioned (like, 11 of 1's in the graph and in the output).

Generally, it is not a good idea to dump double data in a text file, as you will lose precision. Use binary data, like hdf5, protobuf, etc...

```
std::cout << y[i] << std::endl;
std::cout << std::setprecision(16) << y[i] << std::endl;
```

The

```
# without std::setprecision. There are 11 of 1's. The graph has 11 of 1's too.
0.999998
0.999998
0.999999
0.999999
0.999999
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
0.999999
0.999999
0.999999
0.999998

# with std::setprecision
0.999998078189791
0.9999984433334466
0.9999987700410408
0.9999990583125361
0.9999993081478993
0.9999995195471015
0.9999996925101183
0.9999998270369299
0.9999999231275207
0.9999999807818797
1
0.9999999807818797
0.9999999231275207
0.9999998270369299
0.9999996925101183
0.9999995195471015
0.9999993081478993
0.9999990583125361
0.9999987700410408
0.9999984433334466
```

Comment: Thanks. You are right. Actually I had to set precision this way:

ofstream myfile ("gaussian.txt");
myfile.precision(16);